# How to loop over same keys in different YAML files to generate an output per key with Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2

I have got the following YAML files:

```yaml
---
U01:
  ip: 1.1.1.1
U02:
  ip: 2.2.2.2
```

```yaml
---
U01:
  as_bgp: as1
U02:
  as_bgp: as2
```

I am using the following playbook to generate one output per key using the above YAML files

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - name: iterate over up nodes
      include_vars:
        dir: "vars"
        name: U

    - name: print nodes name
      template:
        src: test.j2
        dest: "outputs/{{item.key}}test.txt"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', U) }}"
```

Now, I am using the following simple Jinja2 template

```
{{item.value.ip}}
{{item.value.as_bgp}}
```

How can I modify my playbook to get the fololwing outputs (two separate files):

```
1.1.1.1
as1

2.2.2.2
as2
```

The only things that works is either using `{{item.value.ip}}` or `{{item.value.as_bgp}}` in the Jinja template, it doesn't work for both!

Comment: A key is unique in yaml. If you redeclare it, the last definition wins.

Answer (score 0):

If you do happen to have a really recent version of Ansible (>= 2.12), you could use the [`hash_behaviour`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#parameter-hash_behaviour) parameter of the module `include_vars`, along with a loop and the [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html):

```yaml
- include_vars:
    name: U
    hash_behaviour: merge
    file: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'vars/*', wantlist=True) }}"
  vars:
    U: {}
```

Another option, for older version, would be to `combine` the two dictionaries, with the `recursive=True` option out of the registered output of the `include_vars` task:

```yaml
- include_vars:
    file: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'vars/*', wantlist=True) }}"
  register: include

- template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: "outputs/{{item.key}}test.txt"
  loop: >-
    {{
      include.results
      | map(attribute='ansible_facts')
      | combine(recursive=True)
      | dict2items
    }}
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

---

Given this couple of tasks:

```yaml
- include_vars:
    name: U
    hash_behaviour: merge
    file: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'vars/*', wantlist=True) }}"
  vars:
    U: {}

- debug:
    msg: >-
      For `{{ item.key }}`,
      the IP is `{{ item.value.ip }}`
      and the BGP is `{{ item.value.as_bgp }}`
  loop: "{{ U | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

Or that other couple of tasks:

```yaml
- include_vars:
    file: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'vars/*', wantlist=True) }}"
  register: include

- debug:
    msg: >-
      For `{{ item.key }}`,
      the IP is `{{ item.value.ip }}`
      and the BGP is `{{ item.value.as_bgp }}`
  loop: >-
    {{
      include.results
      | map(attribute='ansible_facts')
      | combine(recursive=True)
      | dict2items
    }}
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

They would all yield:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=U01) => 
  msg: For `U01`, the IP is `1.1.1.1` and the BGP is `as1`
ok: [localhost] => (item=U02) => 
  msg: For `U02`, the IP is `2.2.2.2` and the BGP is `as2`
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your anwser, i've got the follwing error trying the second option (first not possible since i've got Ansible 2.8.2):
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got <generator object do_map at 0xfeca8cec>"}

Comment: Try to add a `| list` before the combine. You should also consider upgrading since your version is unsupported for nearly three years already https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine

Comment: Thanks! it works like a charm, i tried to upgrade Ansible, but since i'm using Cygwin on Windows it is limited to version 2.8.4

Comment: @AhmedElAmineBoukemoune the recommended way to install Ansible is through pip, which should not limit you to any version.

Comment: I will do so, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Given the tree

```yaml
shell> tree vars/
vars/
├── as_bgp.yml
└── ip.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars/as_bgp.yml 
---
U01:
  as_bgp: as1
U02:
  as_bgp: as2
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars/ip.yml 
---
U01:
  ip: 1.1.1.1
U02:
  ip: 2.2.2.2
```

The option *hash_behaviour: merge* works as expected (Ansible 2.12)

```yaml
    - name: iterate over files
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        hash_behaviour: merge
        name: my_vars
      loop: "{{ query('fileglob', 'vars/*') }}"
      vars:
        my_vars: {}
```

gives

```yaml
  my_vars:
    U01:
      as_bgp: as1
      ip: 1.1.1.1
    U02:
      as_bgp: as2
      ip: 2.2.2.2
```

---

If the parameter [hash_behaviour](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#parameter-hash_behaviour) is not available create the names of the variables from the names of the files, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: iterate over files
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "u_{{ item|basename|splitext|first }}"
      loop: "{{ query('fileglob', 'vars/*') }}"
```

will create the variables

```yaml
  query('varnames', '^u_*'):
  - u_as_bgp
  - u_ip
```

In the playbook below, *extract* the variables, and  *combine* the  dictionary *my_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_vars: "{{ query('varnames', '^u_*')|
                 map('extract', hostvars[inventory_hostname])|
                 combine(recursive=True) }}"
  tasks:
    - name: iterate over files
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "u_{{ item|basename|splitext|first }}"
      loop: "{{ query('fileglob', 'vars/*') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_vars:
    U01:
      as_bgp: as1
      ip: 1.1.1.1
    U02:
      as_bgp: as2
      ip: 2.2.2.2
```

The template is trivial

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt.j2
{% for k,v in my_vars.items() %}
{{ v.ip }}
{{ v.as_bgp }}

{% endfor %}
```

The task below

```yaml
    - template:
        src: test.txt.j2
        dest: test.txt
```

will create the file

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt
1.1.1.1
as1

2.2.2.2
as2
```

---

If the option *recursive=True* of the filter *combine* is not available merge the dictionaries on your own, e.g the variables below help to get the same result

```yaml
my_vars: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"
_groups: "{{ query('varnames', '^u_*')|
             map('extract', hostvars[inventory_hostname])|
             map('dict2items')|flatten|
             groupby('key') }}"
_keys: "{{ _groups|map('first')|list }}"
_vals: "{{ _groups|map('last')|
                   map('map', attribute='value')|
                   map('combine')|list }}"
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, i've tried the second option but got the following error:
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleFilterError'>, original message: |combine expects dictionaries, got <generator object do_map at 0xfea5926c>"}

Comment: It's a valid expression ``[dict1, dict2, ...] | combine``. See the [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L325). You'll have to combine the dictionaries in a loop if you're not able to upgrade Ansible.

Comment: I added | list before combined and it worked, i will try upgrading Ansible, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: This means *map* returns a tuple instead of a list. I'd like to find out why. What version of Ansible and Python do you use? Run ``shell> ansible --version``. I don't see the error in Ansible 2.12.1 and Python 3.8.5 on the controller.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, i'm using ansible 2.8.2,  python 3.7.10

Comment: I see. No problem.2.8 is not [supported](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html) anymore. You should consider upgrading. The target is moving rather fast.