# How to include variables with include_vars with the same name without overwriting previous

Tags: ansible

I am having this let's call it `include.yaml`

```
#- name: "Playing with Ansible and Include files"
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  tasks:
    - find: paths="./" recurse=yes patterns="test.yaml"
      register: file_to_exclude
    - debug: var=file_to_exclude.stdout_lines        
    - name: shell
      shell: "find \"$(pwd)\" -name 'test.yaml'"
      register: files_from_dirs     
    - debug: var=files_from_dirs.stdout_lines
    - name: Include variable files
      include_vars: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ files_from_dirs.stdout_lines }}"
    - debug: var=files
```

and 2 ore more test files

```
./dir1/test.yaml
```

that contains

```
files: 
  - file1 
  - file2

./dir2/test.yaml
```

that contains

```
files: 
  - file3 
  - file4
```

the result is

```
TASK [Include variable files] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/mnt/c/Users/GFlorinescu/ansible_scripts/ansible/1st/test.yaml)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/mnt/c/Users/GFlorinescu/ansible_scripts/ansible/2nd/test.yaml)

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "files": [
        "file3",
        "file4"
    ]
}
```

How can I get all the values in files, at the moment the last included `files` variable from last file overrides the `files` from the previous files? Of course without changing the variables names in files `test.yaml`?

In other words I want files to be:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "files": [
        "file1",
        "file2",
        "file3",
        "file4"
    ]
}
```

To be more specific, I ask for any kind of solution or module, even not official or some github module, I don't want a specific `include_vars` module solution.

Comment: Since you are like to append, concatenate or combine variables sourced from different var files, as well overriding the variable precedence behavior, you'll probably find the answer under [In Ansible, how to combine variables from separate files into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554415/in-ansible-how-to-combine-variables-from-separate-files-into-one-array).

Comment: @U880D I think the question you directed in the comment has definitely similar subject, but the question I put is very specific, and since I ask for a solution without specifying exactly which modules to use, also the answers in the link you directed are more than 6 years and possibly obsolete and many of them are contradictory or low quality...

Comment: Even if your question is specific, the root cause of what you are observing is [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and hasn't changed. Ansible still behaves in the same way. You need either write your own vars plugin, change your data structure, merge the files before including or [change how Ansible behaves (but that seems to be deprecated now)](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73089).

Comment: @U880D if you check the response and git repo solution the response is related to  `ansible` version `1.x`

Comment: Maybe [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html) can provide some advantage in your case?

Comment: @U880D I will check,
also I think this might also help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928265/how-to-loop-over-same-keys-in-different-yaml-files-to-generate-an-output-per-key

Comment: Right, but even if the answers are old, the root cause of what you are observing is variable precedence, hasn't changed and is exactly documented as you are observing.

Comment: @U880D that happens with `include_vars`, but I haven't tied the solution to `include_vars` so maybe there are workarounds

Comment: Yes, there are workarounds since you need only to add additional elements to a list. So your question is just about "_How to append items to an existing list?_".

Comment: @U880D yes, but from specific yamls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the included variables into the dictionaries with unique names. For example, create the names from the index of the loop. Then, iterate the names and concatenate the lists

```yaml
    - command: "find {{ playbook_dir }} -name test.yaml"
      register: files_from_dirs

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "{{ name }}"
      loop: "{{ files_from_dirs.stdout_lines }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
        name: "files_{{ ansible_loop.index }}"

    - set_fact:
        files: "{{ files|d([]) + lookup('vars', item).files }}"
      with_varnames: "files_[0-9]+"

    - debug:
        var: files
```

give

```yaml
files:
  - file1
  - file2
  - file3
  - file4
```

---

Notes:

- You have to provide either a path relative to the home directory or an absolute path. See the example below

```yaml
    - command: "echo $PWD"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

give

```yaml
out.stdout: /home/admin
```

For example, when you want to find the files relative to the directory of the playbook

```yaml
    - command: "find {{ playbook_dir }} -name test.yaml"
      register: files_from_dirs     
    - debug:
        var: files_from_dirs.stdout_lines
```

give

```yaml
files_from_dirs.stdout_lines:
  - /export/scratch/tmp8/test-987/dir1/test.yaml
  - /export/scratch/tmp8/test-987/dir2/test.yaml
```

- The same is valid for the module *find*. For example,

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
        recurse: true
        patterns: test.yaml
      register: files_from_dirs
    - debug:
        var: files_from_dirs.files|map(attribute='path')|list
```

give the same result

```yaml
files_from_dirs.files|map(attribute='path')|list:
  - /export/scratch/tmp8/test-987/dir1/test.yaml
  - /export/scratch/tmp8/test-987/dir2/test.yaml
```

- Simplify the code and put the declaration of *files* into the *vars*. For example, the below declaration gives the same result

```yaml
files: "{{ query('varnames', 'files_[0-9]+')|
           map('extract', hostvars.localhost, 'files')|
           flatten }}"
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    files: "{{ query('varnames', 'files_[0-9]+')|
               map('extract', hostvars.localhost, 'files')|
               flatten }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
        recurse: true
        patterns: test.yaml
      register: files_from_dirs

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "{{ name }}"
      loop: "{{ files_from_dirs.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
        name: "files_{{ ansible_loop.index }}"

    - debug:
        var: files
```

---

(maybe off-topic, see comments)

Q: ***"Is there a way to write the path where it was found?"***

A: Yes, it is. See the self-explaining example below. Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1 file_1=alice
host_2 file_2=bob
host_3
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: host_1,host_2,host_3

  vars:

    file_1_list: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.file_1') }}"
    file_2_list: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.file_2') }}"
    file_1_dict: "{{ dict(hostvars|dict2items|
                          selectattr('value.file_1', 'defined')|
                          json_query('[].[key, value.file_1]')) }}"
    file_1_lis2: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                     selectattr('value.file_1', 'defined')|
                     json_query('[].{key: key, file_1: value.file_1}') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |-
          file_1_list: {{ file_1_list }}
          file_2_list: {{ file_2_list }}
          file_1_dict:
            {{ file_1_dict|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
          file_1_lis2:
            {{ file_1_lis2|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    file_1_list: ['alice']
    file_2_list: ['bob']
    file_1_dict:
      host_1: alice
  
    file_1_lis2:
      -   file_1: alice
          key: host_1
```

Comment: is there an alternative to taking them from `hostvars.localhost`?

Comment: Sure. Generally, use `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` . In the above example `hostvars.localhost` is a special case where `inventory_hostname` is `localhost`. You can use *hostvars* of other hosts too, depending on the use case, of course. Open a new question if you have trouble with another use case.

Comment: the variables are definitely on the control machine, since I am not running in ansbile but zuul, but I don't know if zuul changes the place where it keeps those ansible variables, I don't know where to search them either, and I am thinking maybe they are in another place, the code works on my local but on zuul is says Key not found `files_1`, etc

Comment: is there a way to search for the `files_1` key in the whole variables space recursively

Comment: Sure. Use `{{ hostvars | dict2items | json_query('[].value.files_1') }}`

Comment: I am not finding it in `hostvars` I will try `job.host-vars`, but isn't a way to pin those `files_1` under a specific variable I define?

Comment: also is there a way to write the whole dictionary structure, with keys and objects inside?

Comment: Of course, it is. e.g. `{{ hostvars | dict2items | json_query('[].{k1: value.files_1, k2: value.files_2') }}` **Open a new question!**

Comment: is there a way to write the path where it was found ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623257/how-can-i-find-a-key-deep-inside-in-nested-dictionaries-and-show-the-path-to-tha

Comment: still I am unable to find it in hostvars

Comment: I added an example. This is my final comment here.

Comment: I cannot find nothing in `hostvars` either `localhost` or other `host` I think this might be a feature or characteristic of  `zuul-ci` I put another question with my next issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73635936/hostvar-in-playbook-is-not-accessible-in-zuul-while-it-works-in-ansible