# How can I find a key deep inside in nested dictionaries and show the path to that key?

Tags: ansible

Is there find a key deep inside a nested dictionaries and show the path to that key?

Example:

```yaml
---
isbn: 123-456-222
author:
  lastname: Doe
  firstname:
    name: John
    initial: D
```

I want to find the `initial` variable and print the path to it like `author.fistname.initial`

Comment: There is not easy way to achieve this. For example, what should happens if there is a list in the middle of it? You will probably be able to achieve this with a little bit of recursion, with for example, a Jinja macro.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε the [`to_paths` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils) makes it much easier than I actually thought ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Find the initial variable and print the path to it like author.fistname.initial"***

A: Use the dictionaries below. There might be more paths. For example, given the data

```yaml
    data:
      - isbn: 123-456-222
        author:
          lastname: Doe
          firstname:
            name: John
            initial: D
      - isbn: 123-456-333
        author:
          lastname: Doe
          firstname:
            name: Alice
            initial: C
      - isbn: 123-456-444
        author:
          lastname: Doe
          firstname:
            name: Bob
            initial: D
```

- The task creates the dictionary *initials*

```yaml
    - name: Create dictionary initials
      set_fact:
        initials: "{{ initials|d({})|combine({item: authors}) }}"
      loop: "{{ data|json_query('[].*.*.initial')|flatten|unique }}"
      vars:
        authors: "{{ data|
                     selectattr('author.firstname.initial', 'eq', item)|
                     json_query('[].join(`,`,[author.lastname,
                                              author.firstname.name,
                                              author.firstname.initial])') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
initials:
  C:
    - Doe,Alice,C
  D:
    - Doe,John,D
    - Doe,Bob,D
```

- The task creates the dictionary *paths*

```yaml
    - name: Create dictionary paths
      set_fact:
        paths: "{{ paths|d({})|combine(_item, list_merge='append') }}"
      loop: "{{ data }}"
      vars:
        _paths: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.to_paths', item) }}"
        _item: "{{ dict(_paths|dict2items|json_query('[].[value, [key]]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
paths:
  123-456-222:
    - isbn
  123-456-333:
    - isbn
  123-456-444:
    - isbn
  Alice:
    - author.firstname.name
  Bob:
    - author.firstname.name
  C:
    - author.firstname.initial
  D:
    - author.firstname.initial
    - author.firstname.initial
  Doe:
    - author.lastname
    - author.lastname
    - author.lastname
  John:
    - author.firstname.name
```

- Filter unique paths. Create dictionary *paths_unique*

```yaml
    paths_keys: "{{ paths.keys()|list }}"
    paths_vals: "{{ paths.values()|map('unique')|list }}"
    paths_unique: "{{ dict(paths_keys|zip(paths_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
paths_unique:
  123-456-222:
    - isbn
  123-456-333:
    - isbn
  123-456-444:
    - isbn
  Alice:
    - author.firstname.name
  Bob:
    - author.firstname.name
  C:
    - author.firstname.initial
  D:
    - author.firstname.initial
  Doe:
    - author.lastname
  John:
    - author.firstname.name
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data:
      - isbn: 123-456-222
        author:
          lastname: Doe
          firstname:
            name: John
            initial: D
      - isbn: 123-456-333
        author:
          lastname: Doe
          firstname:
            name: Alice
            initial: C
      - isbn: 123-456-444
        author:
          lastname: Doe
          firstname:
            name: Bob
            initial: D

    paths_keys: "{{ paths.keys()|list }}"
    paths_vals: "{{ paths.values()|map('unique')|list }}"
    paths_unique: "{{ dict(paths_keys|zip(paths_vals)) }}"
    
  tasks:

    - name: Create dictionary initials
      set_fact:
        initials: "{{ initials|d({})|combine({item: authors}) }}"
      loop: "{{ data|json_query('[].*.*.initial')|flatten|unique }}"
      vars:
        authors: "{{ data|
                     selectattr('author.firstname.initial', 'eq', item)|
                     json_query('[].join(`,`,[author.lastname,
                                              author.firstname.name,
                                              author.firstname.initial])') }}"
    - debug:
        var: initials

    - name: Create dictionary paths
      set_fact:
        paths: "{{ paths|d({})|combine(_item, list_merge='append') }}"
      loop: "{{ data }}"
      vars:
        _paths: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.to_paths', item) }}"
        _item: "{{ dict(_paths|dict2items|json_query('[].[value, [key]]')) }}"
    - debug:
        var: paths
    - debug:
        var: paths_unique
```

Answer (score 3):

The following playbook does the job using the [`to_paths` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/to_paths_lookup.html)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    isbn: 123-456-222
    author:
      lastname: Doe
      firstname:
        name: John
        initial: D

    needle: initial

  tasks:
    # Note: this is a necessary step to "fix" the value from the lookup.
    # If you set this value in play/task/host/group variable,
    # you will get a recursive loop error any time you use the resulting variable
    - name: extract the info
      set_fact:
        matches: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.to_paths', vars) | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'search', needle) }}"

    - name: Overall info
      debug:
        msg: "I found {{ matches | length }} entries having '{{ needle }}' in their path"

    - name: details
      debug:
        msg: "item at path {{ item.key }} has value: {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ matches }}"
```

Example run:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [extract the info] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Overall info] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I found 1 entries having 'initial' in their path"
}

TASK [details] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'author.firstname.initial', 'value': 'D'}) => {
    "msg": "item at path author.firstname.initial has value: D"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And to be ahead of some possible comments: this works with lists too. Replacing the var `author` above with:

```yaml
    authors:
      - lastname: Doe
        firstname:
          name: John
          initial: D
      - lastname: Perez
        firstname:
          name: Juan
          initial: J
```

gives with the exact same playbook:

```
TASK [Overall info] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I found 2 entries having 'initial' in their path"
}

TASK [details] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'authors[0].firstname.initial', 'value': 'D'}) => {
    "msg": "item at path authors[0].firstname.initial has value: D"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'authors[1].firstname.initial', 'value': 'J'}) => {
    "msg": "item at path authors[1].firstname.initial has value: J"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this using a custom filter.  E.g.:

```
def _findkey_helper(data, want, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    if not data:
        return False, None, None

    if want in data:
        return True, path + [want], data[want]

    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            found, val, foundat = _findkey_helper(v, want, path=path + [k])
            if found:
                return (found, foundat, val)

    return False, None, None


def filter_findkey(data, want):
    """Search a nested dictionary for a given key.

    This filter recursively searches the nested dictionary structure `data`
    for the key `want`. It returns the 3-tuple (found, path, value), where:

    - `found` is True if the named key was found, False otherwise
    - `path` is a dotted path to the named key, or `None` if `found` is False
    - `value` is the corresponding value, or `None` if `found` is False
    """

    found, path, val = _findkey_helper(data, want)
    if found:
        return True, ".".join(path), val
    return False, None, None


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {"findkey": filter_findkey}
```

Drop this into `filter_plugins/findkey.py` adjacent to your playbook, and use it like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    data:
      isbn: 123-456-222
      author:
        lastname: Doe
        firstname:
          name: John
          initial: D
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ data | findkey('initial') }}"
```

The above outputs:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "(True, 'author.firstname.initial', 'D')"
}
```

This only works with nested dictionary structures (that is, it won't search through lists), but necessary changes to support lists would be pretty simple.

Comment: The [`to_paths` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/to_paths_lookup.html) makes this task much easier than I thought and works with lists too out of the box.